# How to change the cell title color when selected in UITableView

Tags: iphone, text, uitableview

HI,
I am using a UITableView to display listings. I have customized it and have added 4 UILabels in the cell, but when the row is selected then the row selection color (customized to green) and Label text color (also a green) remains same. So, it becomes difficult to see the text of cell. I want to change the color of labels to white when row is selected otherwise green.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Look at the `highlightedTextColor` property on the labels. Set that to white and it should do what you want.

Comment: This worked for me. Surprised this is not marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Such is life, glad it helped someone :)

Answer (score 3):

If you’re subclassing `UITableViewCell`, there’s always the [`-setSelected:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW3) method to override.